# react native doesn't fill up window on ipad

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ipad

Any react native project which I am running (including Facebook's examples) look weird on an iPad. It doesn't fill up the screen and everything looks "too big". (there are 2 black bars to the left and right of the content)

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 73):

Solution: In the xcode project, go to the general tab and then to the Deployment Info. There you can change to the device type you want (universal works for both).

If you are using Expo (`create-react-native-app`), modify to your `app.json` to set `ios.supportsTablet` to `true`:

```
"ios": {
    "bundleIdentifier": "your bundle identifier",
    "supportsTablet": true
},
```

Comment: If you are using Expo follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161991/how-do-i-get-a-react-native-app-to-run-properly-on-an-ipad?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: what i have to do in react-native-cli?

Comment: I can't get this to work for react-native-cli. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 32):

If you are using react-native-cli instead of expo, you can open your .xcodeproject with Xcode. Then go to **Build Settings Tab -> Targeted Device Family -> Select Universal.**

Next time you run your project with "react-native run-ios" targeting an iPad device, it will display the app in fullscreen.

Comment: Or you can just select the check box for ipad in General tab

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you you have these 2 checked:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me for Xcode version 13.4.1

Comment: Can confirm, in 2023, this is the only answer that is valid

Answer (score 6):

Simple open your `YOURPROJECT.xcworkspace` in xcode.
Open `General` -> and tick the `ipad` checkbox.
Re-run app.

Chill Pill :)

Answer (score 2):

Update for Xcode 14. Under General > Supported Destinations, click + and then select iPad.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please open Xcode -> open ios folder -> open .xcworkspace in xcode -> choose your project -> select Target -> open General tab -> tick the ipad option in deployment info. Done