# How do I get a React Native app to run properly on an iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, react-native, expo

My React Native app was just rejected by Apple because

> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.3. To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure it runs and displays properly at iPhone resolution on iPad. Even if your app was developed specifically for iPhone, users should still be able to use your app on iPad.

They provided the following screenshot:

[image]

Indeed, it does all look pretty squished, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  This app was built using the Expo SDK.

Comment: could you post your app.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have the following in your `app.json`. Try and set the `supportsTablet` to true.

```
"ios": {
    "bundleIdentifier": "your bundle identifier",
    "supportsTablet": true
},
```

Comment: what i have to do using react-native-cli