# React native application is not using the simulated screen correctly

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, orientation

I recently moved my project from using Expo to React Native CLI. One problem I encounter is that the application is using the Ipad screen in landscape mode, as it was an iPhone in portrait mode. Even when i rotate the device, the application is hard stuck in phone portrait mode. Anybody know how to change this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjSaV.jpg

Comment: I am running: yarn react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Air (4th generation)"

Comment: Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175697/react-native-doesnt-fill-up-window-on-ipad